# How to use Group-Object on this?

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to get all the accounts from `$f` which do not match the accounts in `$table4` into `$accounts`. But I need to also check if the occupancy number matches or not.

CSV `$f`:

```
Account_no |occupant_code
-----------|------------
12345      |    1
67890      |    2
45678      |    3
```

DataTable `$table4`

```
Account_no |occupant_code
-----------|------------
12345      |   1
67890      |   1
45678      |   3
```

Current code:

```
$accounts = Import-Csv $f |
            select account_no, occupant_code |
            where { $table4.account_no -notcontains $_.account_no }
```

What this needs to do is to check that `occupant_code` doesn't match, i.e.:

- *12345*: account and occupant from `$f` and `$table4` match; so it's ignored
- *67890*: account matches `$table4`, but occupancy_code does not match, so it is added to `$accounts`.

Current result:
Desired result: `67890`

I believe I need to use `Group-Object`, but I do not know how to use that correctly.

I tried:

```
Import-Csv $f |
    select account_no, occupant_code |
    Group-Object account_no |
    Where-Object { $_.Group.occupant_code -notcontains $table4.occupant_code }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Compare-Object`?

csv1.csv:

```
Account_no,occupant_code
12345,1
67890,2
45678,3
```

csv2.csv:

```
Account_no,occupant_code
12345,1
67890,1
45678,3
```

PowerShell command:

```
Compare-Object (Import-Csv .\csv1.csv) (Import-Csv .\csv2.csv) -Property occupant_code -PassThru
```

Output:

```
Account_no occupant_code SideIndicator
---------- ------------- -------------
67890      1             =>
67890      2             <=
```

Comment: You need to add `-PassThru`, otherwise you'll lose the actual value the OP is after (the account number for the mismatched occupant codes).

Comment: Indeed, either that or specify both properties so they both show in the output (which produces essentially the same output). Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to [Bill's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45492585/1630171) would be to fill a [hashtable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx) with your reference data (`$table4`) and look up the `occupant_code` value for each account from `$f`, assuming that your account numbers are unique:

```
$ref = @{}
$table4 | ForEach-Object {
    $ref[$_.Account_no] = $_.occupant_code
}

$accounts = Import-Csv $f |
            Where-Object { $_.occupant_code -ne $ref[$_.Account_no] } |
            Select-Object -Expand Account_no
```

Comment: Account numbers are not all unique. There will be duplicates with different Occupant_codes

Answer (score 0):

```
$f | InnerJoin $table4 {$Left.Account_no -eq $Right.Account_no -and $Left.occupant_code -ne $Right.occupant_code} @{Account_no = {$Left.$_}} | Format-Table
```

Result:

```
occupant_code Account_no
------------- ----------
{2, 1}        67890
```

For details see: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848821/in-powershell-whats-the-best-way-to-join-two-tables-into-one/45483110#45483110)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the other answers, you might be able to leverage the `IndexOf()` method on arrays

```
$services = get-service
$services.name.IndexOf("xbgm")
240
```

I am on a tablet right now and don't have a handy way to test it, but something along these lines might work for you:

```
$table4.account_no.IndexOf($_.account_no)
```

should fetch the index your account_no lives in for $table 4, so you could jam it all into one ugly pipe:

```
$accounts = Import-Csv $f | select account_no, occupant_code |
            where { ($table4.account_no -notcontains $_.account_no) -or ($table4[$table4.account_no.IndexOf($_.account_no)].occupant_code -ne $_.occupant_code) }
```

An inner join or a normal loop might just be cleaner though, especially if you want to add some other stuff in. Since someone posted an innerjoin, you could try a loop like:

```
$accounts = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList
$testSet = $table4.account_no
foreach($myThing in Import-Csv $f)
{
    if($myThing.account_no -in $testSet )
    {
        $i = $testSet.IndexOf($myThing.account_no)
        if($table4[$i].occupant_code -eq $myThing.occupant_code) {continue}
    }

    $accounts.add($myThing)
}
```

**Edit for OP, he mentioned $table4 is a data.table**
There is probably a much better way to do this, as I haven't used data.table before, but this seems to work fine:

```
$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable
$col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Account_no,([string])
$col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn occupant_code,([int])
$table.columns.add($col1)
$table.columns.add($col2)

$row = $table.NewRow()
$row.Account_no = "12345"
$row.occupant_code = 1
$table.Rows.Add($row)

$row = $table.NewRow()
$row.Account_no = "67890"
$row.occupant_code = 1
$table.Rows.Add($row)

$row = $table.NewRow()
$row.Account_no = "45678"
$row.occupant_code = 3
$table.Rows.Add($row)

$testList = @()
$testlist += [pscustomobject]@{Account_no = "12345"; occupant_code = 1}
$testlist += [pscustomobject]@{Account_no = "67890"; occupant_code = 2}
$testlist += [pscustomobject]@{Account_no = "45678"; occupant_code = 3}

$accounts = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList
$testSet = $table.account_no
foreach($myThing in $testList)
{
    if($myThing.account_no -in $testSet )
    {
        $i = $testSet.IndexOf($myThing.account_no)
        if($table.Rows[$i].occupant_code -eq $myThing.occupant_code) {continue}
    }

    $accounts.add($myThing) | out-null
}

$accounts
```

Comment: @Simon Yo Ah, I assumed it was an array of objects based on your provided info.  I drafted up test data based on your OP using a data.table for $table and edited it in, hope that helps.