# Check if Two Values in Array / Data Table match

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

I put this question on here before, but I missed an important detail which causes huge issue. There will be duplicate account numbers. So I'm doing it by current_read_date now to avoid duplicates in account number. To ensure values being added to $accounts are new from the CSV.

I am trying to get all the accounts from `$f` which do not match the accounts in `$table4` into `$accounts`. But I need to also check if the current_read_date matches or not.

CSV into Array `$f`:

```
Account_no |occupant_code|current_read_date
-----------|-------------|-----------------
12345      |    1        |  7/17/2017 15:32:00 AM
67890      |    2        |  7/17/2017 12:00:00 AM
45678      |    3        |  7/17/2017 12:00:00 AM
```

DataTable `$table4`

```
Account_no |occupant_code|current_read_date
-----------|-------------|-----------------
12345      |   1         | 7/17/2017 12:00:00 AM
12345      |   1         | 7/17/2017 15:32:00 AM
67890      |   1         | 7/17/2017 13:00:00 AM
67890      |   1         | 7/17/2017 22:00:00 AM
45678      |   3         | 7/17/2017 12:00:00 AM
```

Desired result:

```
$accounts = 
    67890      |    2        |  7/17/2017 12:00:00 AM
```

Current code:

```
$accounts = Import-Csv $f |
            select account_no, current_read_date |
            where { $table4.account_no -notcontains $_.account_no }
```

What this needs to do is to check that `current_read_date` doesn't match, i.e.:

- *12345*: account and date from `$f` and `$table4` match; so it's ignored
- *67890*: account matches `$table4`, but the current_read_date does not match, so it is a new value, thus it is added to `$accounts`.

I believe I need to use `Group-Object`, but I do not know how to use that correctly.

I tried:

```
Import-Csv $f |
    select account_no, occupant_code |
    Group-Object account_no |
    Where-Object { $_.Group.current_read_date -notcontains $table4.current_read_date }
```

This is the previous question:
[How to use Group-Object on this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45492379/how-to-use-group-object-on-this/45497284)

All the answers here failed because I forgot to provide the information that account_no is not unique; there will be frequent duplicates.

All assistance would be greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for awhile.

I've also tried this

```
$testList = @()
$testList = Import-Csv $f | select account_no, occupant_code, current_read_date, current_reading
$accounts = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList

$testSet = $table4
foreach($myThing in $testList)
{
    if($myThing.account_no -in $testSet.account_no )
    {
    foreach($ts in $testSet)
     { 
     if ($myThing.account_no -match $ts.account_no -and $myThing.occupant_code -match $ts.occupant_code)
        {
     $ts.account_no 
     $ts.occupant_code

     }

     else {
    $accounts.add($myThing) | out-null
    write-host $mything
        }
    }
}
```

This fails because it goes through each number, therefore, 12345 will be checked against 67890, and will added 12345 to the $accounts list, even though it already exists, because I cannot compare each individually at a time with table4.

Thanks

Comment: So, basically you want to list the unique account numbers from `$f` that don't have an identical record in `$table4`?

Comment: Yes @AnsgarWiechers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$accounts = $f | Where {
    $Record = $_
    $AccNo = $table4 | Where {$_.Account_no -eq $Record.Account_no}
    !($AccNo | Where {$_.current_read_date -eq $Record.current_read_date})
}
$accounts | Format-Table
```

Result:

```
Account_no occupant_code current_read_date
---------- ------------- -----------------
67890      2             7/17/2017 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Yeah, occupant_code is no longer a constraint, and am matching the CSV to the Table4, so the result would be one instance of account: 67890

Comment: In that case there is no question of joining as there is nothing in the result from the `$table4`. In other words, `$table4` is only used to select the records in the `$f` table. I have change my answer accordingly.

Comment: Didn't know you could write where statements like that. Thank you, this is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Build a reference list from the records in `$table4`

```
$ref = $table4 | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Account_no, $_.occupant_code, $_.current_read_date -join ','
}
```

then filter the records from `$f` by that reference list:

```
$accounts = Import-Csv $f | Where-Object {
    $ref -notcontains ($_.Account_no, $_.occupant_code, $_.current_read_date -join ',')
} | Select-Object -Expand Account_no -Unique
```